# Clear rules of AWS security group for a particular port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to remove all rules for a given port using the "aws ec2"?

```
aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-name MySecurityGroup --protocol tcp --port 22 **--ALL-IP**
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/revoke-security-group-ingress.html), This commands works on either `--cidr` or `--source-group`. so If you have multiple IP addresses then I would say the only option is to run the same command multiple times for the individual IP address (which would take the form of `1.1.1.1/32`).

Or,

You can list all the ipadress in cidr format (1.1.1.1/32) in a file (each ip address on a new line) and then run a `for` loop over it running above command for each iteration. e.g.

```
for i in `cat ip_address_cidr.txt`; do aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-name MySecurityGroup --protocol tcp --port 22 $i; done
```

I have not tested above command  syntax but that should do it so that you can revoke the rules in a single one-liner command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'll try somehow to read the description of the group and to loop through the results.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you are looking for: [How to Close All Open SSH Ports in AWS Security Groups](http://www.quickstepapps.com/?p=180)

Here a solution for a specific security group-id:

```
#!/bin/bash

sg = {security group}

# get the cidrs for the ingress rule
rules=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids $sg --output text --query 'SecurityGroups[*].IpPermissions')
# rules will contain something like:
# 22 tcp 22
# IPRANGES 108.42.177.53/32
# IPRANGES 10.0.0.0/16
# 80 tcp 80
# IPRANGES 0.0.0.0/0
# luckily, aws returns all ipranges per port grouped together

# flag for if we are reading ipranges
reading=0
# loop returned lines
while read -r line; do
    # split the line up
    rulebits=($line)
    # check if if we are reading ssh port ipranges
    if [ $reading -eq 0 ] ; then
        # we are not reading ipranges
        # check if '22 tcp 22'
        if [ ${rulebits[0]} == "22" ] && [ ${rulebits[1]} == "tcp" ] && [ ${rulebits[2]} == "22" ] ; then
            # found it
            reading=1           
        fi
    else
        # we are reading ipranges
        # check if first word is 'IPRANGES'
        if [ ${rulebits[0]} == "IPRANGES" ] ; then
            # found a cidr for open ssh port
            cidr=${rulebits[1]}
            echo -n found port 22 open cidr $cidr closing...
            # close it
            result=$(aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $sg --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $cidr --output text)
            if [ "$result" == "true" ] ; then
                echo " OK"
            else
                echo " ERROR"
            fi
        else
            # new port
            reading=0       
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: solution did not worked for me, but given me idea, i did in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

`revoke-security-group-ingress` in version 2 gives us to specify multiple IP CIDRS. See below solution written in PHP which I am trying to clean in multiple region and multiple prots.

> To specify multiple rules in a single command use the --ip-permissions option https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/revoke-security-group-ingress.html

```
$cleanports = [22,5984];
$sgids = [["sgid"=>"sg1","region"=>"us-east-1"],["sgid"=>"sg1","region"=>"us-east-1"]];
foreach($sgids as $sgidDetail){
    $iprules = json_decode(shell_exec("/usr/bin/aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids {$sgidDetail['sgid']} --region {$sgidDetail['region']} --query 'SecurityGroups[*].IpPermissions'"), true)[0];

    foreach ($iprules as $key => $ips) {
        if(!empty($ips['FromPort']) && !empty($ips['ToPort']) && in_array($ips['FromPort'], $cleanports) && in_array($ips['ToPort'], $cleanports)){
            echo "\n\n";
            echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id {$sgidDetail['sgid']} --region {$sgidDetail['region']} --ip-permissions '".json_encode($ips)."'");
        }        
    }
}
```